# Console Application to emulate command line

Tags: c#, command-line

I am developing a console application. I need to emulate the way how the command line utility behaves when the F7 button is pressed, like shown below:

[image]

Is it possible in C# 2008? If not, is there any workaround available?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm jealous.  *My* F7 doesn't do that...

Comment: This type of UI was traditionally created by directly addressing the video RAM corresponding to text mode of the graphics card.  There used to be tons of libraries out there to build menus, draw windows, etc.  Principally they should work under modern Windows, but it's been so long that I can't recommend anything specific.  If a hotkey (e.g. F7) activates the menu, you are probably looking at a TSR (Terminate and Stay Resident) program... one that starts under DOS, hooks the keyboard, and exits but stays in memory waiting for a specific keypress.

Comment: @Eric J. - amazingly Windows NT has always supported TSRs in the Console: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101921 - but it would be crazy to use that API today - you'd be writing a 16-bit application limited to accessing about 0.025% of a modern PC's memory. In fact I'd wonder if anyone has ever bothered run a TSR on Windows NT or later. There weren't many corporations who ever needed to run 16-bit Windows apps on it.

Comment: @Daniel: I really enjoyed writing TSR's back in the day.  Of course as you point out, things have changed.  Now my cell phone has more memory than my first PC, and 300x as much permanent storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows there is a whole API for writing "Console Mode" applications. It allows you to listen for mouse or keyboard input in an event driven way, and also to set the text foreground and background colours, position the cursor, etc.

To make a box like the one displayed by CMD.EXE, you use certain special characters to make the border (there are various corner pieces and edge pieces - use the Character Map application to see them all).

To use the Console API from C# you probably need to use pinvoke, e.g.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
public static extern bool SetConsoleTextAttribute(
                            IntPtr hConsoleOutput, int wAttributes);
```

See the docs for [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047(VS.85).aspx) to see how to use it to set the colour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if .NET includes wrappers for them or if you'll have to use them via P/Invoke, but the Win32 API includes functions for this. For example, you could use `ReadConsoleOutput` to read the block of the display you're going to cover up. Then you'd use `WriteConsoleOutput` to display your list (including the border). Once you're done with the overlay, you'd restore the previous content with another call to `WriteConsoleOutput`, specifying the block where you saved the underlying data.

Edit: doing a quick check, the right functionality isn't jumping out at me anyway. Maybe I'm missing something obvious though...